# Create an object with input values and add it to an existing array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am following a JavaScript course and I have to create a list of links with JavaScript, by creating the HTML elements with JS, add the style, and insert a form  with JS as well, in order to allow the user to insert a new link on the list.

The problem, is that I could not make the function works to be able to insert the new object(which takes form inputs values) in the existing array and show the list updated with the new link.

Any help on this will be highly appreciated ! and consider that I am a beginner

```js
var listeLiens = [{
    titre: "So Foot",
    url: "http://sofoot.com",
    auteur: "yann.usaille"
  },
  {
    titre: "Guide d'autodéfense numérique",
    url: "http://guide.boum.org",
    auteur: "paulochon"
  },
  {
    titre: "L'encyclopédie en ligne Wikipedia",
    url: "http://Wikipedia.org",
    auteur: "annie.zette"
  },
];

var dlElt = document.createElement("dl");

listeLiens.forEach(function(mot) {

  var dtElt = document.createElement("dt");

  var titreElt = document.createElement("a");
  titreElt.textContent = mot.titre;
  titreElt.href = mot.url;

  var urlElt = document.createElement("span");
  urlElt.textContent = mot.url;


  var auteurElt = document.createElement("p");
  auteurElt.textContent = "Ajouté par " + mot.auteur;

  //STYLES 
  dtElt.style.marginBottom = "10px";
  dtElt.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
  dtElt.style.padding = "15px";

  titreElt.style.color = "#428bca";
  titreElt.style.fontSize = "22px";
  titreElt.style.textDecoration = "none";
  titreElt.style.fontWeight = "bold";

  urlElt.style.marginLeft = "6px";
  urlElt.style.fontSize = "16px";

  auteurElt.style.paddingTop = "5px";
  auteurElt.style.margin = "0px";

  dlElt.appendChild(dtElt);
  dtElt.appendChild(titreElt);
  dtElt.appendChild(urlElt);
  dtElt.appendChild(auteurElt);

});

//form and add new links function 

var zoneForm = document.createElement("div");

var boutonElt = document.createElement("button");
boutonElt.textContent = "Ajouter un lien";
boutonElt.style.borderRadius = "5px";
boutonElt.style.padding = "3px";

var form = document.createElement("form");
form.id = "nouveauLien";
form.style.width = "100%";

var auteur = document.createElement("input");
auteur.placeholder = "Enter link name";
auteur.id = "auteur";
auteur.setAttribute('type', "text");
auteur.setAttribute('name', "auteur");

var titre = document.createElement("input");
titre.placeholder = "Enter title name";
titre.style.marginLeft = "40px";
titre.style.width = "18%";
titre.id = "titre";
titre.setAttribute('type', "text");
titre.setAttribute('name', "titre");

var url = document.createElement("input");
url.placeholder = "Enter link address";
url.style.marginLeft = "40px";
url.style.width = "23%";
url.setAttribute('type', "text");
url.setAttribute('name', "url");

var boutonValider = document.createElement("input");
boutonValider.style.marginLeft = "40px";
boutonValider.style.borderRadius = "5px";
boutonValider.style.width = "7%";
boutonValider.style.padding = "3px";
boutonValider.setAttribute('type', "submit");
boutonValider.setAttribute('value', "Ajouter");


form.appendChild(auteur);
form.appendChild(titre);
form.appendChild(url);
form.appendChild(boutonValider);
zoneForm.appendChild(boutonElt);

boutonElt.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (boutonElt) {
    boutonElt.style.display = 'none';
    form.style.display = 'inline-block';
    zoneForm.appendChild(form);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nouveauLien").style.display = "none";
  }
});

boutonValider.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var message = document.createElement("p");
  message.textContent = "link already added! ";
  var message2 = "Try again";

  var newObject = {
    titre: document.getElementsByName('titre').value,
    url: document.getElementsByName('url').value,
    auteur: document.getElementsByName('auteur').value
  };
  listeLiens.push(newObject);


  if (boutonValider) {
    boutonElt.style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("nouveauLien").style.display = "none";
    return message;
  } else {
    return message2;
  }

});


document.getElementById("contenu").appendChild(zoneForm);

document.getElementById("contenu").appendChild(dlElt);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

span {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 80%;
}

.lien {
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/liensweb.css">
  <title>Activity 2</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Activity 2</h1>

  <!-- New elements into this tag -->
  <div id="contenu">
  </div>

  <script src="../js/liensweb.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please try putting all the snippets into one snippet so that we can run them all together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've corrected several mistakes from your code, following is the working code,

```js
  

 var listeLiens = [{
    titre: "So Foot",
    url: "http://sofoot.com",
    auteur: "yann.usaille"
  },
  {
    titre: "Guide d'autodéfense numérique",
    url: "http://guide.boum.org",
    auteur: "paulochon"
  },
  {
    titre: "L'encyclopédie en ligne Wikipedia",
    url: "http://Wikipedia.org",
    auteur: "annie.zette"
  },

];


var dlElt = document.createElement("dl");

listeLiens.forEach(function(mot) {
   appendObjToList(mot);
});

function appendObjToList(mot) {
  var dtElt = document.createElement("dt");

  var titreElt = document.createElement("a");
  titreElt.textContent = mot.titre;
  titreElt.href = mot.url;

  var urlElt = document.createElement("span");
  urlElt.textContent = mot.url;


  var auteurElt = document.createElement("p");
  auteurElt.textContent = "Ajouté par " + mot.auteur;

  //STYLES 
  dtElt.style.marginBottom = "10px";
  dtElt.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
  dtElt.style.padding = "15px";

  titreElt.style.color = "#428bca";
  titreElt.style.fontSize = "22px";
  titreElt.style.textDecoration = "none";
  titreElt.style.fontWeight = "bold";

  urlElt.style.marginLeft = "6px";
  urlElt.style.fontSize = "16px";

  auteurElt.style.paddingTop = "5px";
  auteurElt.style.margin = "0px";

  dlElt.appendChild(dtElt);
  dtElt.appendChild(titreElt);
  dtElt.appendChild(urlElt);
  dtElt.appendChild(auteurElt);
}

//form and add new links function 

var zoneForm = document.createElement("div");

var boutonElt = document.createElement("button");
boutonElt.textContent = "Ajouter un lien";
boutonElt.style.borderRadius = "5px";
boutonElt.style.padding = "3px";

var form = document.createElement("form");
form.id = "nouveauLien";
form.style.width = "100%";

var auteur = document.createElement("input");
auteur.placeholder = "Enter link name";
auteur.id = "auteur";
auteur.setAttribute('type', "text");
auteur.setAttribute('name', "auteur");

var titre = document.createElement("input");
titre.placeholder = "Enter title name";
titre.style.marginLeft = "40px";
titre.style.width = "18%";
titre.id = "titre";
titre.setAttribute('type', "text");
titre.setAttribute('name', "titre");

var url = document.createElement("input");
url.placeholder = "Enter link address";
url.style.marginLeft = "40px";
url.style.width = "23%";
url.setAttribute('type', "text");
url.setAttribute('name', "url");

var boutonValider = document.createElement("input");
boutonValider.style.marginLeft = "40px";
boutonValider.style.borderRadius = "5px";
boutonValider.style.width = "7%";
boutonValider.style.padding = "3px";
boutonValider.setAttribute('type', "button");
boutonValider.setAttribute('value', "Ajouter");


form.appendChild(auteur);
form.appendChild(titre);
form.appendChild(url);
form.appendChild(boutonValider);
zoneForm.appendChild(boutonElt);

boutonElt.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (boutonElt) {
    boutonElt.style.display = 'none';
    form.style.display = 'inline-block';
    zoneForm.appendChild(form);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nouveauLien").style.display = "none";
  }
});

boutonValider.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var message = document.createElement("p");
  message.textContent = "link already added! ";
  var message2 = "Try again";

  var newObject = {
    titre: document.getElementById('titre').value,
    url: document.getElementsByName('url')[0].value,
    auteur: document.getElementById('auteur').value
  };
  listeLiens.push(newObject);
  appendObjToList(newObject);

  if (boutonValider) {
    form.style.display = 'none';
    boutonElt.style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("nouveauLien").style.display = "none";
    return message;
  } else {
    return message2;
  }

});


document.getElementById("contenu").appendChild(zoneForm);

document.getElementById("contenu").appendChild(dlElt);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

span {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 80%;
}

.lien {
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Activity 2</h1>

  <!-- New elements into this tag -->
  <div id="contenu">
  </div>
```

As to why it didn't work earlier, here are the mistakes,

1. Initially when the page loaded, you populated 3 list objects in the DOM, but after user adds one more object, it was not updated in the DOM, but only in the list object.
2. The show/hide actions for the form wasn't right. Hiding a container will hide all its children but not vice versa.
3. document.getElementById returns an element whereas document.getElementsByName returns an array of elements, you can read the docs for more on similar functions.
4. You made the boutonValider to be of type 'submit' which would try to post the form to empty url and reload the page every time that button is clicked, it has to be of type 'button' if you're going to handle everything in javascript.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works perfectly now, many thanks for the advices as well!